# Trace of positive operator

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

Let $A$ be a bounded $\ge 0$ operator on separable complex Hilbert space $\mathscr{H}$. By the spectral theorem, we know that there exists a unitary transform $U:\mathscr{H} \rightarrow L^2 (\mu)$ and finite measure $\mu$ and $f\in L^\infty (\mu),f\ge0$ such that
\begin{equation}
UAU^*\psi =f \psi
\end{equation}
Is it true that
\begin{equation}
\operatorname{tr}{A}=\int fd\mu
\end{equation}
How would one prove this?

Comment: If this was true in general, it would imply that every bounded non-negative operator has finite trace, which is not true.